# How do I pass **C.char data back to caller's buffer?

Tags: go, jna, cgo

I am going to build a Go shared object binary (.DLL and .so) that passes back a string to Java. To work out the C string passing from Go I wrote this:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"
import (
    "log"
    "unsafe"
)

//export passBackHello
func passBackHello(buf **C.char) C.int {
    str := "Hello World!"
    length := len(str)
    cString := C.CString(str) // returns *C.char
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cString))
    log.Println("In passBackHello: cString:", C.GoStringN(cString, C.int(length)))
    *buf = C.CString(str) // works
    *buf = cString        // doesn't work
    log.Println("In passBackHello: buf:", C.GoStringN(*buf, C.int(length)))

    return C.int(length)
}

func main() {
    buf := make([]byte, 8192) //create my buffer
    cStrPointer := (**C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0]))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cStrPointer))
    lengthCint := passBackHello(cStrPointer)
    log.Println("In main: length:", int(lengthCint))
    log.Println("In main: buf:", C.GoStringN(*cStrPointer, lengthCint))
    log.Println("In main: buf:", C.GoString(*cStrPointer))
}
```

When I use `*buf = C.CString(str)` in function `passBackHello` it works:

```
2018/03/31 19:33:54 In passBackHello: cString: Hello World!
2018/03/31 19:33:54 In passBackHello: buf: Hello World!
2018/03/31 19:33:54 In main: length: 12
2018/03/31 19:33:54 In main: buf: Hello World!
2018/03/31 19:33:54 In main: buf: Hello World!
exit status 3221226356
```

When I use `*buf = cStringPointer` in function `passBackHello` it shows in `buf` while in `passBackHello` but not in `main`:

```
2018/03/31 19:33:05 In passBackHello: cString: Hello World!
2018/03/31 19:33:05 In passBackHello: buf: Hello World!
2018/03/31 19:33:05 In main: length: 12
2018/03/31 19:33:05 In main: buf:  ⌂3     X☺�
2018/03/31 19:33:05 In main: buf:  ⌂3
exit status 3221226356
```

I need to get the `*buf = cStringPointer` version to work because that one has the `C.free` of the C string variable. I am running go version go1.10.1 windows/amd64.

**UPDATE**

After applying [Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem)'s answer and some other cleanup the working Go code looks like this:

```
//export passBackHello
func passBackHello(cStrPointer **C.char) C.int {
    str := "Hello World!"
    length := len(str)
    *cStrPointer = C.CString(str) // copies *C.char into caller's buffer
    log.Println("In passBackHello *cStrPointer:", C.GoStringN(*cStrPointer, C.int(length)))
    return C.int(length)
}

func main() {
    buf := make([]byte, 8192) //create my buffer
    cStrPointer := (**C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0]))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cStrPointer))
    lengthCint := passBackHello(cStrPointer)
    log.Println("In main: length:", int(lengthCint))
    log.Println("In main: *cStrPointer:", C.GoStringN(*cStrPointer, lengthCint))
    log.Println("In main: *cStrPointer:", C.GoString(*cStrPointer))
}
```

And just to be complete the Java caller looks like this:

```
// allocate a void**
final PointerByReference decCStringPointer = new PointerByReference();
// call the C function
Integer decLength = gpg.passBackHello(decCStringPointer);
// extract the void* that was allocated in C
final Pointer p = decCStringPointer.getValue();
// extract the null-terminated string from the Pointer
final String decValue = p.getString(0);
System.out.printf("decrypted length: %d\n", decLength);
System.out.printf("decrypted value: %s\n", decValue);
```

It looks like the buffer is in C memory. How do I free it from Java?

Comment: Can you comment the `defer` call in `passBackHello` function and try again? The reason I'm seeing is that it is being freed after the assignment. But, technically, you should be freeing it in your `main` (as you're already doing) that means it is a dangling pointer. Can you confirm that please?

Comment: Another thing is that that `C.CString` allocates the memory and return the pointer so you don't need that `buf` in `main`. The pointer is enough and it'll be pointing to the string. You just have to free it after use. See: https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/.

Comment: cString in passBackHello has no pointer accessible from func main.  So C.free needed to be done in passBackHello .  However, does "*buf = C.CString(str)" leave behind a C string allocation?  In not, there's no need for a C.free.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I got that. You're returning a string in `buf` which is then received in `main` and it should be freed there. Isn't that so? And, when you do `defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cString))`,  it frees the memory which is pointed to by `buf` after assignment. Can you run it without the `defer` statement?

Comment: To free the string from the Java side after you're done with the string, I suggest you create a Go function which takes a pointer and frees it. Then you just call this function from the Java side. Sure, you could just directly call `free` from via JNA, but theoretically cgo might use a different memory allocator in the case of which you might have undesired consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`C.CString`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) function:

```
// Go string to C string
// The C string is allocated in the C heap using malloc.
// It is the caller's responsibility to arrange for it to be
// freed, such as by calling C.free (be sure to include stdlib.h
// if C.free is needed).
func C.CString(string) *C.char
```

You don't need to free it in your function. It is the caller (i.e. `main` function in your case) that is supposed to free it.

Remove the line `defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cString))` from your `passBackHello` and it should work!

**NOTE**:
You don't need that buffer (i.e. `buf`) because it's the pointer that is being returned and the memory is already allocated. You may copy it in your buffer if required and free the pointer.